# Why "npm get global" always return true even I have set "npm set global=false" in MAC Lion

Tags: node.js, npm

I have set "npm set global=false", but I still get true after "npm get global" (It should be returned with false). I rebooted my MAC, but got the same result.

I'm troubled for several days  and can not get it resolved.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this with the `--local` switch:

```
npm set global=false --local
```